# how to write the "if" datetime interval statement that triggers a popup alert window?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery [FullCalendar plug-in](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my asp.net app. I need an alert window to come up when requestors click on a day in the calendar to reserve a date that is less than three weeks away.

I have the code for the alert that works, like

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view);
alert('The requested date is within the 3 week reservation window.');
```

But I'm in trouble with a "three weeks" "if" statement/condition, like

```
if date<=date(+21)
```

that should trigger the alert pop-up.

Could you please help?
Thank you in advance very much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have answered your question. Please don't forget to vote up or accept an answer if it has helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Dates always seem to be a bit of problem.

But is actually easy in your case. Here is a working solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/7MTdn/